# Partitioning a list

Tags: list-manipulation

I have a list of the following kind:

```
{{1,0.5},{2,0.6},{3,0.8},{-4,0.9},{-3,0.95}}
```

The important property is, that somewhere in the list, the first element of the sublists changes sign (above is from + to -, but could be from - to +). How can I most efficiently split this into two lists:

```
{{1,0.5},{2,0.6},{3,0.8}}
```

and

```
{{-4,0.9},{-3,0.95}}
```

?

Comment: What happens when the sign switches back? A list for each consecutive run of + and -?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
list = {{1, 0.5}, {2, 0.6}, {3, 0.8}, {-4, 0.9}, {-3, 0.95}};

SplitBy[#, Sign[First @ #] &] & @ list
```

> {{{1, 0.5}, {2, 0.6}, {3, 0.8}}, {{-4, 0.9}, {-3, 0.95}}}

Or

```
Split[#,  SameQ @@ Sign [First /@ {##}] &] & @ list
```

> {{{1, 0.5}, {2, 0.6}, {3, 0.8}}, {{-4, 0.9}, {-3, 0.95}}}

Answer (score 2):

This works on your example data, but it might not be general enough to satisfy you, but it is the best I can do with only one example.

```
data = {{1, 0.5}, {2, 0.6}, {3, 0.8}, {-4, 0.9}, {-3, 0.95}};
Column[{d1, d2} = SplitBy[data, Sign @* First]]
```

[image: split]

`Column`, of course, is only used form display.